# data.table::fread and Unbalanced "

Tags: r, data.table, fread

When I tried to read a csv file using `data.table:fread(fn, sep='\t', header=T)`, it gives an "Unbalanced " observed on this line" error. The data has 3 integer variables and 1 string variable. The strings in the csv file are not enclosed with `"`, and yes there are some lines that contains `"` within the string variable and the `"` characters are not in pairs.

I am wondering is it possible to let `fread` just ignore the unpaired `"` in the variable and continue reading data? Thanks.

Here is the sample data(just one record)

```
N_ID    VISIT_DATE  REQ_URL REQType
175931  2013-3-8 23:40:30   http://aaa.com/rest/api2.do?api=getSetMobileSession&data={"imei":"60893ZTE-CN13cd","appkey":"android_client","content":"Z0JiRA0qPFtWM3BYVltmcx5MWF9ZS0YLdW1ydXoqPycuJS8idXdlY3R0TGBtU   1
```

Comment: Can you please add the first lines of your file to the question? Note that fread is still under development and embedded quotes ("\"" and """") have problems...

Comment: without reproducing your error there's little we can help with (unless one has experienced the exact problem you're facing).

Comment: I have added the sample record. Please verify. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:  Now implemented in v1.8.11**

From NEWS :

> fread now accepts quotes (both ' and ") in the middle of fields,
>   whether the field starts with " or not, rather than the 'unbalanced
>   quotes' error, #2694. Thanks to baidao for reporting. It was known and
>   documented at the top of ?fread (text now removed). If a field starts
>   with " it must end with " (necessary if the field separator itself is in the
>   field contents). Embedded quotes can be in column names too. Newlines (\n)
>   still can't be in quoted fields or quoted column names, yet.

---

Yes as @agstudy said, embedded quotes are a known documented problem not yet implemented since `fread` is new. Strictly speaking, I suppose these ones aren't embedded because the string in your example doesn't start with a quote, though.

Anyway, I've filed this as a bug report so it doesn't get forgotten. To be done in the next release. Thanks for highlighting.

[#2694 : Strings including quotes but not starting with quote in fread](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=975&func=detail&aid=2694)

Comment: Has this been fixed?  I'm having a similar issue processing tweets, I believe the tweet_text fields have \n characters that should be ignored.

Comment: @ZacharyST  Did you search README and did you test?  If still a problem please find and +1 (or raise a new) GitHub issue.