# read.table not working for importing a .dat

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to import a data set from a `.dat` file off the internet using the `read.table` command.  I usually have no issues when the file is formatted, for example:

```
A B
1 2
3 4
```

But this data set is formatted

```
A B A B
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

(You can find the data set I'm having issues with here: [https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jeffwu/book/data/BrainandBodyWeight.dat](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Ejeffwu/book/data/BrainandBodyWeight.dat))

My current line of code is:

```
Data2 = read.table("https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jeffwu/book/data/BrainandBodyWeight.dat", header = TRUE)
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
> = dec,  :    line 1 did not have 12 elements

Comment: If you are just trying to read as is then use fill=TRUE parameter in read.table, `read.table("https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jeffwu/book/data/BrainandBodyWeight.dat", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`, since the later columns don't contain any values, it will be populated with NAs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue when importing dataset: \`Error in scan(...): line 1 did not have 145 elements\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161009/issue-when-importing-dataset-error-in-scan-line-1-did-not-have-145-eleme)

Comment: @PKumar that worked to get rid of the error but I need just two columns.  The data set is just two column names but is displayed as 6 different columns with each name showing up twice.  I am trying to get all the data into the appropriate column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there are spaces in the header row, so just skip that with `skip = 1`.

From there, we can extract the even and odd rows using a repeating logical vector `c(TRUE, FALSE)` and `c(FALSE, TRUE)`.

The final line of the data has some empty values, so remove those with `complete.cases()`.

```
data <- read.table("https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jeffwu/book/data/BrainandBodyWeight.dat",
                   header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, skip = 1)

result <- data.frame(Body.Wt = unname(unlist(data[,c(T,F)])),
                     Brain.Wt = unname(unlist(data[,c(F,T)])))

result <- result[complete.cases(result),]
head(result)
  Body.Wt Brain.Wt
1   3.385     44.5
2   0.480     15.5
3   1.350      8.1
4 465.000    423.0
5  36.330    119.5
6  27.660    115.0
```