# Error reading .csv file from website into R

Tags: r, csv

I try to read .csv file from website into R as following:

```
poll = read.csv("http://www.aec.gov.au/About_AEC/cea-   notices/files/2013/prdelms.gaz.statics.130901.09.00.02.csv")
```

But then I got the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
    EOF within quoted string
```

Then I [searched previous StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415028/1036500), and changed my code to:

```
poll = read.csv("http://www.aec.gov.au/About_AEC/cea-notices/files/2013/prdelms.gaz.statics.130901.09.00.02.csv", quote="")
```

This seemed to solve problem, I got no warning, and got 8855 * 26 data. My question is:

What did the original problem mean, and why did the second code fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains a symbol ", but this symbol is normally interpreted as a quote. This broke the line that contains the symbol. You have to disable the use of this symbol as a quote.