# read.csv warning 'EOF within quoted string' prevents complete reading of file

Tags: r

I have a problem reading a csv in R.
I use

```
logfile <- read.csv(path
                  ,header=TRUE
                  ,dec="."
                  ,quote="\""
                  , sep=","
                  ,colClasses=c("character","character"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE #?EOF problem
)
```

to read a csv.
This command breaks in the middel of the csv with the message:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

Disabling the quoting does not work, because of some multiline entries in the file.

Here is an example file: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8867381/RAS_ERROR_ascii_reproducible.csv.html

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: A minimal reproducible would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [read.csv warning 'EOF within quoted string' prevents complete reading of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414776/read-csv-warning-eof-within-quoted-string-prevents-complete-reading-of-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `data.table`'s `fread` it will throw an error but warn you to append a new line at the end of the file. If you follow this and append a `"\r\n"` to the end of the file, `fread` will read the file correctly (even with default parameters).