# Reading a csv file with embedded quotes into R

Tags: r, csv, statistics, double-quotes

I have to work with a .csv file that comes like this:

```
"IDEA ID,""IDEA TITLE"",""VOTE VALUE"""
"56144,""Net Present Value PLUS (NPV+)"",1"
"56144,""Net Present Value PLUS (NPV+)"",1"
```

If I use read.csv, I obtain a data frame with one variable. What I need is a data frame with three columns, where columns are separated by commas. How can I handle the quotes at the beginning of the line and the end of the line?

Comment: Please see `quote` option of `read.csv`.

Comment: This is probably the answer you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415028/1036500

Comment: possible duplicate of [read.csv warning 'EOF within quoted string' prevents complete reading of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414776/read-csv-warning-eof-within-quoted-string-prevents-complete-reading-of-file)

Comment: I don't think these linked questions will actually answer the OP's question ...

Comment: Yikes. How did someone manage to screw up a csv file so badly? Do you have any idea why they formatted it this way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's going to be an easy way to do this without stripping the initial and terminal quotation marks first. If you have `sed` on your system (Unix [Linux/MacOS] or Windows+Cygwin?) then

```
read.csv(pipe("sed -e 's/^\"//' -e 's/\"$//' qtest.csv"))
```

should work.  Otherwise

```
read.csv(text=gsub("(^\"|\"$)","",readLines("qtest.csv")))
```

is a little less efficient for big files (you have to read in the whole thing before processing it), but should work anywhere.

(There may be a way to do the regular expression for `sed` in the same, more-compact form using parentheses that the second example uses, but I got tired of trying to sort out [where all the backslashes belonged](http://xkcd.com/234/).)

Comment: Would you also recommend changing the back-to-back double quote in the middle of the string to a single double quote?

Comment: not sure what you mean here.  The middle of which string?  The regexp in the second example is meant to signify "beginning of line followed by double-quote OR double-quote followed by end of line" ...

Comment: Right. You are dealing with the ones at the end of the lines (if I'm reading that right). There is also `""IDEA TITLE""`. Won't those quotes mess things up?

Comment: @Fo.: I didn't think so, but those answers do work (with a bit of adaptation) here.  However, I still think my `sed`-based answer might be faster, where `sed` is available ...

Comment: @Fo., are you repeating yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest both removing the initial/terminal quotes and turning the back-to-back double quotes into single double quotes. The latter is crucial in case some of the strings contain commas themselves, as in

```r
"1,""A mostly harmless string"",11"
"2,""Another mostly harmless string"",12"
"3,""These, commas, cause, trouble"",13"
```

Removing only the initial/terminal quotes while keeping the back-to-back quote leads the `read.csv()` function to produce 6 variables, as it interprets all commas in the last row as value separators. So the complete code might look like this:

```r
data.text <- readLines("fullofquotes.csv")  # Reads data from file into a character vector.
data.text <- gsub("^\"|\"$", "", data.text) # Removes initial/terminal quotes.
data.text <- gsub("\"\"", "\"", data.text)  # Replaces "" by ".
data <- read.csv(text=data.text, header=FALSE)
```

Or, of course, all in a single line

```r
data <- read.csv(text=gsub("\"\"", "\"", gsub("^\"|\"$", "", readLines("fullofquotes.csv", header=FALSE))))
```