# Getting error when reading tab demilited file: "EOF within quoted string"

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a tab delimited file in R and getting following error. I have more than 2 million records in file but its extracting only 1.2 million records.

Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string

Answer (score 2):

As you indicate yourself the problem lies in the fact that `'` are recognized as quotes, and this will cause R to interpret anything between this and the next quotation mark as on character string. See also [here](https://biowize.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/quotation-marks-and-rs-read-table-function/) for a longer explanation. The easy solution is to disable quoting altogether using quote = "".

For future reference, please check earlier posts first, since the same solution was given in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414776/read-csv-warning-eof-within-quoted-string-prevents-complete-reading-of-file).

Answer (score 0):

I read the file in notepad++ and it was reading it correctly. Finally, I tried removing all prime symbols (') from the text file using notepad++ and it worked for me.