# r - convert single column data frame to data frame with rows based on one fixed text

Tags: r, transform

**Update 1**

Linking the actual dataset since the solutions given for the example data are not working out for me.

Link: https://app.box.com/s/65j1enr13pi51i44mfrymccklw1artot

Please note that `LOT` is the end of the row marker.

--

I've data frame like the following (single column):

```
D
2
f
h
k
END_ROW_WORD
k
1
2
END_ROW_WORD
e
g
j
2
k
END_ROW_WORD
```

I'd like to convert it into following format:

[image]

As you can see there is a specific word (END_ROW_WORD) that marks the end of the row.

Comment: And what is now the end row marker? You have `PAST LOT`, `LOT` but also `PAST AUCTION` and `AUCTION`.

Comment: `LOT` is the end row marker.

Comment: The problem with your complete dataset is that a) you have several words per row (not single letters as shown here) and b) all kinds of special characters which makes finding a appropriate delimiter difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first puts a newline character, `"\n"`, after every `"END_ROW_WORD"` marker, then pastes the result into a long character string.
Then, it uses `read.table` to read the data in from a text connection.

```
end <- "END_ROW_WORD"

inx <- c(0, grep(end, dat[[1]]))
s <- NULL
for(i in seq_along(inx)[-1]){
    s <- c(s, dat[[1]][(inx[(i - 1)] + 1):inx[i]], "\n")
}

con <- textConnection(paste(s, collapse = " "))
result <- read.table(con, fill = TRUE)
close(con)
result
#  V1 V2 V3           V4 V5           V6
#1  D  2  f            h  k END_ROW_WORD
#2  k  1  2 END_ROW_WORD                
#3  e  g  j            2  k END_ROW_WORD
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(V1 = c("D", "2", "f", "h", "k", "END_ROW_WORD", 
"k", "1", "2", "END_ROW_WORD", "e", "g", "j", "2", "k", "END_ROW_WORD"
)), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

**EDIT.**

After the question's edit by the OP, I revised the code to see if that file can be properly read into a `data.frame`. The main difficulty is that the file has many non printable characters, and `read.table` was having trouble getting to the end of the file.

**Credits** to the solution of this problem go to the accepted answer in [read.csv warning 'EOF within quoted string' prevents complete reading of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414776/read-csv-warning-eof-within-quoted-string-prevents-complete-reading-of-file). I upvoted both the question and that answer.

**Credits** must also be given to @kath, in the answer the idea of using a string replace to put newline characters as EOL markers is much better than my ugly `for` loop above. Unlike kath, I use `base R` only, I don't find it necessary to load an external package.

Now the revised code.

```
# Use this first pattern if AUCTION also marks the end of a row
#pattern <- "(^LOT|^AUCTION)"
pattern <- "(^LOT)"

dat <- readLines("data_.csv")
s <- gsub("[[:cntrl:]]", "", dat)
s <- sub(pattern, "\\1\n", s)

con <- textConnection(paste(s, collapse = "\t"))
result <- read.table(con, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, quote = "", row.names = NULL)
close(con)

head(result)
tail(result)
str(result)
```

I thought that there would be some empty rows, so I checked it with the following code.

```
#
# See if there are any empty rows
#
empty <- apply(result, 1, function(x) nchar(trimws(paste0(x, collapse = ""))) == 0)
sum(empty)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow the solution did not work out when I applied it on the actual dataset. I've updated the question now.

Comment: @user709413 See the edit. Maybe it now does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar approach to Alejandro's, but using `split` instead of a `for` loop:

```
colstarts <- diff(c(0, which(df == "END_ROW_WORD")))
rows <- split(df[[1]], rep(1:length(colstarts), colstarts))
rows <- lapply(rows, `length<-`, max(lengths(rows)))
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, rows))
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `for`-loops, but with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
new_text <- str_c(df$V1, collapse = " ")
new_text <- str_replace_all(new_text, "END_ROW_WORD", "END_ROW_WORD\n")
read.table(text = new_text, fill = T)

#   V1 V2 V3           V4 V5           V6
# 1  D  2  f            h  k END_ROW_WORD
# 2  k  1  2 END_ROW_WORD                
# 3  e  g  j            2  k END_ROW_WORD
```

**Data**

```
df <- 
  structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 5L),
                                .Label = c("1", "2", "D", "e", "END_ROW_WORD", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k"),
                                class = "factor")),
            .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Updated the question with actual dataset as the solution didn't work out for me,

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do it but it works

```
pos_help = which(grepl("END_ROW_WORD",data))

d = list()
for(i in 1:length(pos_help)){
  if(i == 1){
    d[[i]] = data[1:pos_help[1]]
  } else {
    d[[i]] = data[(pos_help[i-1]+1):pos_help[i]]
  }
}
dataFrame = do.call(rbind,lapply(d, "length<-", max(lengths(d))))
```

Answer (score 0):

without loop, but using map and split.... (because why not :p )

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x=c(
  "D",
  "2",
  "f",
  "h",
  "k",
  "END_ROW_WORD",
  "k",
  "1",
  "2",
  "END_ROW_WORD",
  "e",
  "g",
  "j",
  "2",
  "k",
  "END_ROW_WORD"
)  

)
split(df,cut(1:16,breaks=c(0,which(df == "END_ROW_WORD")))) %>%
  map_dfc(~rbind(.x,tibble(x=rep(NA,(6-nrow(.x)))))) %>% 
  t() %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've linked the real data set as the solution for the example data didn't give desired result.