# Using r, I can't process one specific IPA (Intl. Phonetic Alphabet) font when reading it off a website

Tags: r

Using R, I am reading a dictinary entry of specific words off the dictionary website (I use 'cat' as an example here). I do succeed in reading it into an R data frame. When I try to create a new variable off it, R is not recognizing the specific letter, æ. Could you advise?

This below is supposed to get 'k1t' for the new variable I'm creating (HL_IPA), but I am getting instead 'kæt', which is a result of R not being able to process 'æ'. This happens only to this letter. Thanks in advance.

```
library(tidyverse)

x2 <-read.delim("https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cat", encoding="UTF-8")
dplyr::filter(x2, grepl('ipa dipa', x2$X..doctype.html.))->temp1
#table(x2$X..doctype.html.)
head(temp1, 1)->temp2
table(temp2$X..doctype.html.)
temp2$pos = regexpr('lpl-1>', temp2$X..doctype.html.)
temp2$endpos = regexpr('</span>/</span></span>', temp2$X..doctype.html.)
temp2$pos =temp2$pos +6
temp2$Cambridge = substr(temp2$X..doctype.html.,temp2$pos,temp2$endpos-1)

temp2$HL_IPA<- gsub('y|r|w|d|æ|ə|ʌ',"1",temp2$Cambridge)
temp2<- select(temp2,Cambridge,HL_IPA)
temp2$HL_IPA
```

FYI, I get this warning messge. Thanks.

```r
> x2 <-read.delim("https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cat", encoding="UTF-8")
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

Comment: googling [`"R" "EOF within quoted string"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="R"+"EOF+within+quoted+string") came up with some really similar sounding problems going back many years, with some clear resolutions, I suggest you start with https://stackoverflow.com/q/17414776/3358272 and https://kbroman.org/blog/2017/08/08/eof-within-quoted-string/. If you want to stick within the SO realm, try [`EOF within quoted string [r]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=EOF+within+quoted+string+%5Br%5D)

Comment: Ultimately, adding `quote=""` resolved the warning, but ... what I get back is not a frame. If you are looking to scrape data from the web page, look into `rvest`, reading an HTML page as a `data.frame` is not going to work easily for you. It'd make more sense to just `x2 <-readLines("https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cat", encoding="UTF-8")` and then work on parsing the HTML ... or use `rvest`, since it's much better at it than mere mortals like you and me :-)