# fread() error and strange behaviour when reading csv

Tags: r, data.table

I used `fread()` from `data.table` library to try read a 540MB csv file. It returned an error message saying:

```
' ends field 36 on line 4 when detecting types: 20.00,8/25/2006 0:00:00,"07:05:00 PM","CST",143.00,"OTTAWA","KS","HAIL",1.00,"S","MINNEAPOLIS",8/25/2006 0:00:00,"07:05:00 PM",0.00,,1.00,"S","MINNEAPOLIS",0.00,0.00,,88.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,,0.00,,"TOP","KANSAS, East",,3907.00,9743.00,3907.00,9743.00,"Dime to nickel sized hail.
```

I have no idea what caused the error and want to track down if it's a bug or just some data formating issue that I can tweak `fread()` to process.

I managed to read the csv using `read.csv()`, and decided to track down the row that triggered the error above (line 617174, not line 4 as the error message above). I then re-output the row and one row each immediately preceding and following the offending row, written out using `write.csv()` as `testout.csv`

I was able to read back `testout.csv` using `read.csv()` creating a data frame with 3 observations, as expected. Using `fread()` on `testout.csv`, however, resulted in a data table with only 1 observation, which is the last row.

The four lines in `testout.csv` are below (I start a new line for each entry below for readability).

> "STATE__","BGN_DATE","BGN_TIME","TIME_ZONE","COUNTY","COUNTYNAME","STATE","EVTYPE","BGN_RANGE","BGN_AZI","BGN_LOCATI","END_DATE","END_TIME","COUNTY_END","COUNTYENDN","END_RANGE","END_AZI","END_LOCATI","LENGTH","WIDTH","F","MAG","FATALITIES","INJURIES","PROPDMG","PROPDMGEXP","CROPDMG","CROPDMGEXP","WFO","STATEOFFIC","ZONENAMES","LATITUDE","LONGITUDE","LATITUDE_E","LONGITUDE_","REMARKS","REFNUM"
>
> 20,"8/25/2006 0:00:00","07:01:00 PM","CST",139,"OSAGE","KS","TSTM WIND",5,"WNW","OSAGE CITY","8/25/2006 0:00:00","07:01:00 PM",0,NA,5,"WNW","OSAGE CITY",0,0,NA,52,0,0,0,"",0,"","TOP","KANSAS, East","",3840,9554,3840,9554,".",617129
>
> 20,"8/25/2006 0:00:00","07:05:00 PM","CST",143,"OTTAWA","KS","HAIL",1,"S","MINNEAPOLIS","8/25/2006 0:00:00","07:05:00 PM",0,NA,1,"S","MINNEAPOLIS",0,0,NA,88,0,0,0,"",0,"","TOP","KANSAS, East","",3907,9743,3907,9743,"Dime to nickel sized hail.
>   .",617130
>
> 20,"8/25/2006 0:00:00","07:07:00 PM","CST",125,"MONTGOMERY","KS","TSTM WIND",3,"N","COFFEYVILLE","8/25/2006 0:00:00","07:07:00 PM",0,NA,3,"N","COFFEYVILLE",0,0,NA,61,0,0,0,"",0,"","ICT","KANSAS, Southeast","",3705,9538,3705,9538,"",617131

When I ran `fread("testout.csv", sep=",", verbose=TRUE)`, the output was

```
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is  1.05E-06B
File is opened and mapped ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Looking for supplied sep ',' on line 5 (the last non blank line in the first 'autostart') ... found ok
Found 37 columns
First row with 37 fields occurs on line 5 (either column names or first row of data)
Some fields on line 5 are not type character (or are empty). Treating as a data row and using default column names.
Count of eol after first data row: 2
Subtracted 1 for last eol and any trailing empty lines, leaving 1 data rows
Type codes: 1444144414444111441111111414444111141 (first 5 rows)
Type codes: 1444144414444111441111111414444111141 (after applying colClasses and integer64)
Type codes: 1444144414444111441111111414444111141 (after applying drop or select (if supplied)
```

Any idea what may have caused the unexpected results, and the error in the first place? And any way around it? Just to be clear, my aim is to be able to use `fread()` to read the main file, even though `read.csv()` works so far.

Comment: What happens if you use `read.table` (invoking more options than available with `read.csv`) from the base package?

Comment: `dfrt <- read.table("testout.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")` gave me the same result as the output from `read.csv`, as expected.

Comment: Are there line breaks in the file, perhaps inside quoted fields?  If so, fread can't cope with that yet.  On the line after the 4th one you show, in the penultimate field, which is "" on the 4th line.

Comment: Or in the "dime to nickel" field. See those 2 periods. Is read.csv converting the newline to dot?  I think fread should retain the newline when it deals with it - what you think?

Comment: Thanks Matt, you're right. I just checked the data again, the 2 periods after "dime to nickel" has a newline in it, which doesn't reflect in the text above.

I think `fread` should retain the newline if `sep` is explicitly set as something else. In auto behaviour, I guess the newline will confuse things. But in cases like csv file above, with the delimiter being quite explicit, I think newline should be treated just like any other characters. That seems to be the way `read.csv` handles it, which gives a reassuring consistency.

Comment: So if `fread` can't cope with newline in quoted fields yet, am I right that the only work around is still to read with other means e.g. `read.csv` into a data frame, and then convert the data frame to data table?

Comment: Yes I'm afraid so. It's been raised a few times so will try and get to it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: Now fixed in v1.9.3 on GitHub :

> - fread() now accepts line breaks inside quoted fields. Thanks to Clayton Stanley for highlighting.
>   See:
>     [fread and a quoted multi-line column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006661/fread-and-a-quoted-multi-line-column-value)

Windows users are reporting [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375832/fread-and-column-with-a-trailing-backslash/24377685#comment37731803_24377685) with the latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/).

Comment: I am still having the same error as Ricky after installing v1.9.3 from GitHub.  However, I am using a Mac platform (x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0).  I must be taking the same course that Ricky took because my assignment is identical.