# fread and column with a trailing backslash

Tags: r, data.table

I have a problem with fread() reading a column of directory paths using "\" as the directory separator.  The issue is that the trailing directory separator throws an error in fread().

For the below example csv file,

```
file,size
"windows\user",123
```

both fread() and read.csv() agree and both convert the \ to \\

```
> fread("example.csv")
            file size
1: windows\\user  123
```

However, for the following example fread() gives an error while read.csv() is fine.

```
file,size
"windows\user\",123
```

read.csv() gives

```
> read.csv("example.csv")
             file size
1 windows\\user\\  123
```

While the fread() error looks like this

```
> fread("example.csv",verbose=TRUE)
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 0.000 GB
File is opened and mapped ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Using line 2 to detect sep (the last non blank line in the first 'autostart') ... sep=','
Found 2 columns
First row with 2 fields occurs on line 1 (either column names or first row of data)
All the fields on line 1 are character fields. Treating as the column names.
Count of eol after first data row: 2
Subtracted 1 for last eol and any trailing empty lines, leaving 1 data rows
Error in fread("example.csv", verbose = TRUE) : 
' ends field 1 on line 1 when detecting types: "windows\user\",123
```

I would really like to avoid doing

```
DT = data.table(read.csv("example.csv"))
```

if at all possible.

Comment: As it happens, I've just been fixing that along with `\n` inside quoted fields. Will add answer when it's ready to try from [GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/).

Comment: It does make one wonder what would be the "right" fix since it is due to the well-documented behavior of `scan` and contrary to this questioner's claims, the example is NOT fine with read.csv(). 'file,size
"windows\user\",123`  throws an error.

Comment: @BondedDust `read.csv` seems to read it fine for me, agreeing with the asker. I looked in `?scan` - where do you mean?

Comment: `scan` interprets the '\user' as ctrl-u followed by 'ser'. `read.csv(text="windows\user\",123", sep=",")` returns: 
Error: '\u' used without hex digits in character string starting ""windows\u". Mac 10.8.5, R 3.1.0

Comment: @BondedDust That's not `read.csv`, that's the parser.  Try typing `"windows\user\",123"` at the console on its own and you get the same error. To parse you need to double the \. When reading from a file with contents as shown by asker, `read.csv(filename)` works.

Comment: Right. I erred by assuming that `read.csv(text=.)` would fully duplicate disk access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now fixed in v1.9.3 on [GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/).

> - fread() now accepts trailing backslash in quoted fields. Thanks to user2970844 for highlighting.

```
$ cat example.csv
file,size
"windows\user\",123

> require(data.table)
> fread("example.csv")
              file size
1: windows\\user\\  123
> read.csv("example.csv")
             file size
1 windows\\user\\  123
>
```

Comment: That's two fixes I've seen in the last couple of days.  It's really nice to see things get done that fast.  Thank you.

Comment: I just compiled the github version and it seems to work for my actual data, but for my toy example fread gives me an empty data.table.  I'm sure this is just a corner case, but try `fread("file,size\n\"windows\\user\\\",123\n")`

Comment: @user2970844 I included your example in the test suite (tests 1337 & 1338) so should be ok. Could you run `test.data.table()` and let me know the last line please. I pasted that command as well and works for me. I'm at `"All 1341.3 tests ... completed ok"`

Comment: Test 1010.1, 1011 ran without errors but failed check that x equals y:

Comment: @JacobColvin Thanks but what's the last line (how many tests were run)? That's the easiest way to establish which commit you have.

Comment: I"m running windows 8 fyi,...
Test 1010.1, 1011, 1328, 1332, 1335, 1337, 1338, 1341.1, 1341.2, 1341.3 ran without errors but failed check that x equals y:
Test 1324, 1333 didn't produce correct error :
Test 1336 Error in fread(f) : 
  Expected sep (',') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 5 on line 3 when detecting types: "TX",77406,"business analyst\\\\\\\","the boeing co","",""

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  13 errors out of 1341.3 in inst/tests/tests.Rraw on Tue Jun 24 11:17:30 2014. Search tests.Rraw for test numbers: 1010.1, 1011, 1324, 1328, 1332, 1333, 1335, 1336, 1337, 1338, 1341.1, 1341.2, 1341.3. The test() function is defined at the top of tests.Rraw and contains usage info.

Comment: Thanks. Could you copy the full output somewhere like www.copy.com, or email it to me at `maintainer("data.table")`.  I ran on winbuilder and only 1010.1 and 1011 fail (looks like a \r issue). So maybe it is Win8.  Also your `sessionInfo()` please.

Comment: Sorry... I reinstalled from github and noticed a warning about a dll not being copied.  I think it was because I had an existing R session already opened.  Now everything is working as expected, and I only get the two errors (1010.1, 1011) you previously mentioned from winbuilder. Thank you very much @MattDowle.

Comment: @JacobColvin That's a relief! Thanks for the update.