# Package installation failed when trying to install from GitHub

Tags: r, github, data.table, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to run the following command in RStudio (version 3.1.0 on Windows 7 64-bit):

```
devtools::install_github("data.table", "Rdatatable")
```

I get the following output:

```
Installing github repo data.table/master from Rdatatable
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpcrtx8Y/master.zip
Installing data.table
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD build  \
  "C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpcrtx8Y\devtoolsd343a7c2b57\data.table-master" --no-manual  \
  --no-resave-data 

* checking for file 'C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpcrtx8Y\devtoolsd343a7c2b57\data.table-master/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'data.table':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to build vignettes
Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL -l "C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMlGNWp\Rinst2786d3f6fc5" --no-multiarch "C:/Users/cle1394/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMlGNWp/Rbuild27856a15b8f/data.table"' had status 1
      -----------------------------------
* installing *source* package 'data.table' ...
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="data.table.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="assign.o bmerge.o chmatch.o dogroups.o fastmean.o fastradixdouble.o fastradixint.o fcast.o fmelt.o forder.o fread.o gsumm.o init.o rbindlist.o reorder.o uniqlist.o vecseq.o wrappers.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'data.table'
* removing 'C:/Users/cle1394/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMlGNWp/Rinst2786d3f6fc5/data.table'
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I have tried installing Rtools; the screenshots of the installation are found below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

After restarting RStudio, and running the command again, I get the same output.  Is there something I am missing?  Why can't I install this package from github?

**Edit:** Added sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] devtools_1.5   digest_0.6.4   evaluate_0.5.5 httr_0.3       memoise_0.2.1  parallel_3.1.0
 [7] RCurl_1.95-4.1 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.0    whisker_0.3-2
```

**Edit:** Added has_devel():

```
> has_devel()
Error: could not find function "has_devel"
```

Comment: Note that the current way to call `install_github` is: `install_github("Rdatatable/data.table")`

Comment: @Thomas Thank you but that seems to give the same result as before.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't matter, just letting you know about the current syntax. Can you also include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your post. I can't reproduce this on Windows 7 x64 with R 3.1.0.

Comment: My personal experience is that compiling on Windows is flakey. You should try getting R itself to build (after carefully following all steps in the building guide [its particular]) and then try the package.

Comment: Not sure, but following [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19505252/559784), what do you get when you do: `has_devel()` (from `devtools` package)? Please edit the output to your answer.

Comment: @Arun `has_devel()` output.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388, I did mention it's from `devtools` package. Which means you'll have to load it first and then run the command!

Comment: @Arun Thank so much.  My problem was, since I was running the command `devtools::install_github` without immediately being told the `devtools` package wasn't included, I assumed that it was included.  Once I ran the command `require(devtools)` and then ran `devtools:::install_github("data.table", "Rdatatable", build_vignettes=FALSE)` it works.  Thanks, again.

Comment: Hm, not sure why that solved it. Maybe for windows, it's essential to actually load `devtools`?? In any case, I'm glad it fixed your issue.

Comment: @Arun Just noticed (from user1477388's comment above) we had an extra colon in the 2nd command on our github page. That explains why the command worked at all (via namespace) without `require` first.  Have edited that on our page now.  Thanks and sorry for the hassle user1477388.

Comment: @MattDowle No problem, thanks so much for a super-efficient means of importing data.  I still don't quite know how it's several times faster than the other methods that are currently available.  Unfortunately, I have been pulled onto another project (C# MVC) so I have to put my R work on hold!  Also, I ran the `build_vignettes=F` command because the other one complained about `pdfLatex` which I remember from your README doc.

Comment: @Arun Please post your answer for me to accept at your earliest convenience.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer an open question.
The `install_github` function accepts `build_vignettes` logical (not documented as it is passed to dots for `install` function).
In case of error on building vignettes you may use: `devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes=FALSE)`.
Argument `build_vignettes` has recently changed its default value from `TRUE` to `FALSE`, so using recent version of `devtools` you don't have to care about it.