# Interpreting new line \n character when reading from file using fread in r

Tags: r, fread

I can't get `fread` in the `data.table` package to handle new lines (\n) as intended. They comes out as "\n" rather than a new line (`head` show "\\n" instead of "\n"). According to this post below I understand that `fread` should be able to handle this situation:
[fread and a quoted multi-line column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006661/fread-and-a-quoted-multi-line-column-value)

I have tried quoting ("string") the values column with the same result. Is there a simple solution or parameter that I have missed? Should they be escaped somehow? Here is an example illustrating the problem, as well as my implementation:

[Edit:] Some clarification, so you don't need to read the code to follow. The content of the *strings.txt* is shown in the code comment below `# strings.txt`. The file is a tab separated text file with four columns and three rows plus a header row. The first entry in the file, `strMsg1`, is identical to `strAsIntended`. However, `fread` adds an additional backslash to \n when reading from the file, which makes the new line character into a literal \n. How can this be avoided? I just need to be able to code new lines into my strings. Hope that was understandable.

[Edit2:] The result is shown in this figure.
[image]

```
library(data.table)
library(gWidgets2)

# strings.txt
# scope order   key value
# test_gui  1   strMsg1 Text with new line characters:\n1) The first point and the\n2) second point should be on separate lines\n\nThen perhaps some text below, separated by an empty line.
# test_gui  2   strMsg2 Some text does not contain new line characters.
# test_gui  3   strMsg3 Expand window to see text and button widgets

strAsIntended <- "Text with new line characters:\n1) The first point and the\n2) second point should be on separate lines\n\nThen perhaps some text below, separated by an empty line."
filePath <- "C:\\path\\to\\strings.txt"

# Read file.
dt <- fread(file = filePath, sep = "\t", encoding = "UTF-8")
head(dt) # \n has become \\n

# Set key column.
setkey(dt, key = "key")

# Get strings for the specific function.
dt <- dt[dt$scope == "test_gui", ]

# Get strings.
strText <- dt["strMsg1"]$value
strButton <- dt["strMsg2"]$value
strWinTitle <- dt["strMsg3"]$value

# Construct gui.
w <- gwindow(title = strWinTitle)
g <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container = w, expand = TRUE, fill = "both")
gtext(text = strText, container = g)
gtext(text = strAsIntended, container = g)
gbutton(text = strButton, container = g)
```

[Edit3:] @user2554330 Thanks for the explanation and solution. That was indeed not how I thought it worked.

Here is an updated working code example with screenshot below:

```
library(data.table)
library(gWidgets2)

# strings.txt
# scope order   key value
# test_gui  1   strMsg1 Text with new line characters:\n1) The first point and the\n2) second point should be on separate lines\n\nThen perhaps some text below, separated by an empty line.
# test_gui  2   strMsg2 Some text does not contain new line characters.
# test_gui  3   strMsg3 Expand window to see text and button widgets

strAsIntended <- "Text with new line characters:\n1) The first point and the\n2) second point should be on separate lines\n\nThen perhaps some text below, separated by an empty line."
filePath <- "C:\\Users\\oskar\\OneDrive\\Dokument\\R\\win-library\\3.6\\strvalidator\\extdata\\languages\\strings.txt"

# Read file.
dt <- fread(file = filePath, sep = "\t", encoding = "UTF-8")

# Check data. Not identical.
print(dt[1]$value) # print adds backslash \\n
print(strAsIntended) # prints \n
cat(dt[1]$value) # cat prints as is \n
cat(strAsIntended) # prints with new line

# Set key column.
setkey(dt, key = "key")

# Get strings for the specific function.
dt <- dt[dt$scope == "test_gui", ]

# Fix new line character.
dt[ , value:=gsub("\\n", "\n", value, fixed = TRUE)]

# Cehck data. Now identical and prints \n
print(dt[1]$value)
print(strAsIntended) 
# Now identical and prints with a new line.
cat(dt[1]$value)
cat(strAsIntended)

# Get strings.
strText <- dt["strMsg1"]$value
strButton <- dt["strMsg2"]$value
strWinTitle <- dt["strMsg3"]$value

# Construct gui.
w <- gwindow(title = strWinTitle)
g <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container = w, expand = TRUE, fill = "both")
gtext(text = strText, container = g)
gtext(text = strAsIntended, container = g)
gbutton(text = strButton, container = g)
```

[image]

Running:

R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yWjZ.jpg) LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

Comment: We don't know what is in your `strings.txt` file.

Comment: It's in the comment in the code example below # strings.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what `fread` is doing.  Your input file contains a backslash followed by `n`, and that's what the string from `fread` contains.  However, when you print a string containing a backslash, it is doubled. (Use `cat()` to print it if you don't want this.) Your `strAsIntended` variable doesn't contain a backslash, it contains a single newline character, which is displayed as `\n` when printed.

If you want to **convert** the `\n` in your input file into a newline character, used `gsub` or another substitution function.  For example,

```
dt[,3] <- gsub("\\n", "\n", dt[,3], fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That was not how I thought it worked. Updated example with the fix:     `dt[ , value:=gsub("\\n", "\n", value, fixed = TRUE)]`